# Ubuntu 9.10: find video card drivers for Nvidia Geforce 320M graphics card?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Can you please tell me how can I find video drivers for Nvidia Geforce 320M graphics card for Ubuntu 9.10?

Comment: Hrm. I wonder how many minutes my honest response to this would last before a moderator deleted it...

Comment: And I suppose you want drivers for your Creative soundcard, too.

Comment: How can I find that?

Comment: @Ignacio: At least the binary blob for Nvidia is in the package repos...No one packages Creative soundcard drivers, unless they've finally opened (I heard rumors to that effect ages ago).

Answer (score 2):

First thing: you're already using a driver, it's called nv. It's a pile of obfuscated unmaintainable code, so upgrade to 10.04 and use the nouveau driver, which is a lot better.

If you want 3D acceleration, you're stuck using the binary-only nvidia driver. You can install this with

```
System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers
```

It may also be called "Restricted Drivers": the driver is restricted by copyright and it is not Free Software.